# Django ORM: Many to Many Self-Reference with Through Model

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a many-to-many self-referencing relationship that includes a through model. Products are composed of other Products, including an amount (I.E a screw is made from iron rods). I made the through model, although I can't seem to access the 'amount' field in the through model:

**Model code:**

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    produced = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='RecipeComponent', symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RecipeComponent(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item")
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ingredient")
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.amount) + " of " + self.ingredient.name
```

I've tried a number of other queries, but as you can see they seem to fail. I know I'm missing something but I can't put my finger on it.

```
screw.ingredients.all()
>>> <QuerySet [<Product: iron_rod>]>
screw.ingredients.all()[0].amount
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>>>     AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'amount'
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but I _think_ you are supposed to exclusively access the through instance, i.e. `screw.recipecomponent_set.all()[0].amount`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do this before as well -

`print(screw.recipecomponent_set.all())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'recipecomponent_set'`

Comment: I am sorry, didn't notice that you have `related_name`s. Try `screw.ingredient.all()...` (not `ingredients`).

Comment: This one seems to return an empty set:
`screw.ingredient.all() ->
<QuerySet []>`

Comment: Are you sure your `Product` instance (`screw`) has any `RecipeComponent` instances associated? I think you also name the relations a bit confusingly. Is `screw` a main item or an ingredient? If it is a main item you should use `screw.item.all()` (which looks, _confusing_, as I mentioned).

Comment: Yes. Screw is an instance of Product, which is related to Iron_bar as the Item of the RecipeComponent. You can see that in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

```
screw.ingredients.all()[0]
```

Is a product, and if you try:

```
 screw.ingredients.all()[0].amount
```

you're trying to access the `amount` attribute of `Product` which does not have. Hence the error:

```
>>> AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'amount'.
```

If you want to get the amount describing some relation you can:

```
relation_data = RecipeComponent.objects.get(product=screw, ingredient=wood)
relation_data.amount  # The amount of wood for screw.
```

Or you want to know how many different ingredients has screw:

```
RecipeComponent.objects.filter(product=screw).count()
```

Comment: Thank you-Is there no way to access this relation from the Product model itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method within your Product class that returns the amount of the given ingredient:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    def get_amount_of_ingredient(self, ingredient):
        try:
            return RecipeComponent.objects.get(item=self, ingredient=ingredient).amount
        except RecipeComponent.DoesNotExist:
            return 0
```

Then call it from `screw` object:

```
screw.get_amount_of_ingredient("iron_rod")
```